# Load new page after ajax call to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm running into an issue where the page is failing to load (or rather, it's doing nothing) upon an ajax request to a specified controller.

Sending the ajax with an ID to load up a populated view model and then loading the view with said view model. I'm not looking to load a partial view, as this call is happening within a chartjs bar graph selection, where the user clicks on a bar and it will call the event to load up the ajax function with the ID to load the "details" page.

This controller called is used elsewhere, however this is the first time being called in an ajax method.

Is it failing because ajax is requring some type of partial view post back, and not a full view? Is there a way to load the view with the view model from an ajax call?

Note, the ID is successfully getting to the controller method and everything is executing as expected, loading the view is the issue.

**Javascript/ajax inside view**

```
.
. Nested ajax call here
.                
                historyGraph.onclick = function(evt) {
                var activePoints = myChart.getElementsAtEvent(evt);
                var firstPoint = activePoints[0];
                var executionId = idData[firstPoint._index];

                if (firstPoint !== undefined) {
                    goToDetailsPage(executionId);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

function goToDetailsPage(executionId) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("Details", "TestSuiteExecutions")",
        data: { 'testSuiteExecutionId': executionId },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json"
    });
}
```

**Controller Method**

```
        public ActionResult Details(int testSuiteExecutionId)
    {
        var resultsModel =
            this.testSuiteExecutionModelService.GetTestSuiteExecutionResultsModelForTestSuiteExecutionId(
                testSuiteExecutionId);

        return View("Details", resultsModel);
    }
```

Comment: If you are not returning a partial view, why making an ajax call ? Why not do a normal navigation to the details action method ? `location.href="yourUrlToDetailsPage"`

Comment: It doesn't look like `Details` is marked as an `[HttpPost]` method. Also, it doesn't look like you actually do anything with the response in your ajax call. There should be a `success: function(result){ //todo: use result }` in there. Ajax does not cause a page reload though, that is its purpose. In order to automatically reload the page, you should just submit a form instead.

Comment: @TravisJ is there a way to create a form to send to a controller within a javascript function?

Comment: Sure, just prepare the url with the querystring and set window.location to that url.

Comment: Alright, I set up the querystring and it works now, thanks!